# cannot find a way to switch to telex text input style in ibus-unikey (for Vietnamese language)

Tags: keyboard-layout

ubuntu 14.04 desktop 64 bit version (from 13.10 64 bit)

### system upgraded via software updater

ibus-unikey works fine with English and Vietnamese languages choices, however i can only use one type of keyboard for Vietnamese language without the option to switch to the telex text entry style.

i have tried many options and still failed to find a way to change the keyboard layout.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to choose telex typing via text entry menu:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22321883/Workspace%201_040.png

You can show this menu by launching "Text entry" via launch pad and then tick the checkbox shown in the image below:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22321883/Text%20Entry_041.png

Regarding keyboard layout, I didn't find a way to use DVORAK instead of QWERTY.